# php remove a line after specific words with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

there is text in file as example:

```
<div class="from">jack</span></div>
hey u

<div class="from">ron</span></div>
bye
```

i am trying to delete the new line tag after "" and replace "|"

the result i need is:

```
<div class="from">jack</span></div>|hey u

<div class="from">ron</span></div>|bye
```

i tried this but think i got it wrong because it do the job.

```
$string = file_get_contents($filename);
$string = str_replace('/(<\/span><\/div>\r\n)', '|', $string);
file_put_contents($filename, $string);
```

what is the correct way?

thanks

Comment: Your ending a span that doesnt have an opening tag. Thats bad HTML.

Comment: Also you dont want to replace the whole line, you want to read 2 lines and then remove the \r\n and join them

Comment: @Husman the html is in middle of trriming. origanaly there is opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '<div class="from"><span>jack</span></div>
hey u';

echo preg_replace('/\r\n/', '|', $string);
```

Comment: Thats part of the solution. How does he concatenate 2 lines in the file?

Comment: @Husman `file_put_contents($filename, $string, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: i need it on multiple text in the file as example. (i edited the question now to be more clear) thisanswer will to all file to one line. no?

Comment: You need to isolate the chunks that you apply the preg_replace. If it's always going to be a span and div then you could possibly use: `preg_replace('/\<\/span\>\<\/div\>\r\n/', '</span></div>|', $string);` http://codepad.org/eFapTGyY

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$text = "";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   if (strpos($line,'<div>') !== false) {
      $line = preg_replace('/\r\n/', '|', $line)
   }
   $text .= $line;
}
file_put_contents($filename, $text);
fclose($file_handle);
```

Hows that for reading the file line by line, if the line has a  tag, it replaces \n\r, and then at the end writes all of the lines back into the file.

Comment: i need it on multiple text in the file as example. (i edited the question now to be more clear) your answer will to all file to one line. no?

Comment: Modified algorithm to read line by line and do replace on each line if it contains a div.

Comment: thank you !
for some reason its return error 500. i did run it like this:
<?php 
$filename = 'example1.txt';
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$text = "";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   if (strpos($line,'<div>') !== false) {
      $line = preg_replace('/\r\n/', '|', $line)
   }
   $text .= $line;
}
file_put_contents($filename, $text);
fclose($file_handle);

?>

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what line ending is used, there's three possible ones, \n, \r\n, and \r.

Try this:

```
$string = str_replace('/(<\/span><\/div>\n)', '|', $string);
```

Also the first slash in that string is suspect, so try this:

```
$string = str_replace('(<\/span><\/div>\r\n)', '(<\/span><\/div>|', $string);
```